# Windows 10 Education after finishing school

Tags: windows-10, license

What happens if I have a Windows 10 Education license on my PC and I finish school? Does my Windows detect that I am no longer a student? Are there any drawbacks after finishing scool? Or can I use seamlessly my computer for years without any problem?

Comment: Microsoft offers _tons_ of different licenses and license terms, and continually tunes the technical enforcement (activation etc.) of those terms. So you should probably ask your school about this - they are the only ones who know (hopefully) what the license terms are (and the consequences of violation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EULA of DreamSpark says the following when ordering your free products.

> 2. TERMS FOR DREAMSPARK DIRECT SUBSCRIPTION.
>
>    a.    DreamSpark Direct Subscription. Subject to the terms of this agreement, the DreamSpark Direct Subscription provides a subscription to access software. Microsoft may change the software or other offerings that it makes available under the DreamSpark Direct Subscription at any time without prior notice to you.
>
>    b.    End of Student Status. The DreamSpark Direct Subscription is a special offering for students. Once you no longer qualify for the DreamSpark Direct Subscription (due to graduation or otherwise no longer meeting the definition of "you" above), your DreamSpark Direct Subscription will terminate; **however, you may continue to use the software you obtained prior to termination of your student status subject to the terms of this agreement.**
>
>    c.   Termination. Microsoft may terminate the entire DreamSpark program or your specific DreamSpark Direct Subscription at any time without prior notice to you for any reason or no reason.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply one of the many versions of Windows. Windows 10 Education is for both students and faculty. Its designed for increased security and ease of deployment. Unlike Office 365, the license does not require renewing. You should check with your school as there may be specific licensing restrictions you agreed to as a student.

> Windows 10 Education is available exclusively for academic customers
>   in Volume Licensing programs. Windows 10 Education includes features
>   from Windows 10 Enterprise that are ideal for advanced security and
>   the comprehensive device control and management needs of today’s
>   educational institutions. Windows 10 Education also enables simplified
>   deployment with a direct path for many devices to upgrade from Windows
>   10 Home or Windows 10 Pro. MDOP is included to help institutions
>   manage their IT environments.

[source PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/d/1/2d14fe17-66c2-4d4c-af73-e122930b60f6/windows-10-volume-licensing-guide.pdf)